# Have tag pictures in the blog posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog

I recently wrote a post for the blog, and I was told that it needed links to some tags.

So, merrily on my way, i edit my post to put the [justice-league](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/justice-league) tag (with tag picture included) into the post to find out I can't.

Could we add this feature to the blog? or would it not be possible because the blog is on a different website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now accomplish this by using a shortcode.  Use the following format:

`[tag]star-trek[/tag]`

Comment: Nice!  I've updated the posts that I could find that have links to tag pages to use this.

Comment: It looks perfect!

Answer (score 2):

By tag picture, you mean this?

[image]

It would be difficult to have this automatically applied to tag links (or to automatically convert something like [ tag : my-tag-name ] into [my-tag-name](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-tag-name)), because the blog is a fairly standard (as far as I can tell) WordPress installation.  (Presumably a WordPress plug-in could be created that provided this functionality).

I don't think it's possible to even add the background image in the HTML view of the WordPress editor (I tried this and it appeared to ignore the inline style).

We could create images ourselves and use those (uploaded images go into a library that's usable for all posts).  I'm not sure it's worth the effort, though.

Comment: I think it would look good for consistency.